Generalised tangent bundles of a complex variety.
Let $\Bbbk=\mathbb{C}$. Let $X$ be a $\Bbbk$-variety. Let $A$ be an Artinian local $\Bbbk$-algebra with residue field $\Bbbk$. I wonder whether the following is correct.

There exists a $\Bbbk$-variety $X_A$ such that
$$\{A\textrm{-points of }X\}\cong\{\Bbbk\textrm{-points of }X_A\}. $$

The set of $A$-points of $X$ is the set of morphisms $\mathrm{Spec}(A)\to X$ over $\Bbbk$.
Moreover, we define a functor
$$\mathrm{F}:\mathbf{Art}^{\mathrm{loc}}_\Bbbk\times \mathbf{Var}_\Bbbk\to\mathbf{Set}, \quad\mathrm{F}(A,X):=\{A\textrm{-points of }X\}. $$
The question becomes the following.

Is there a functor $$\mathrm{G}:\mathbf{Art}^{\mathrm{loc}}_\Bbbk\times \mathbf{Var}_\Bbbk\to\mathbf{Var}_\Bbbk$$ such that
$$\mathrm{F}=\mathrm{F}(\Bbbk,-)\circ\mathrm{G}? $$

If they fail, what kind of conditions are needed on $(X,A)$?

Since $A$-points of $X$ is the same as $A$-points of $X \times_{\Bbbk} A$, you can take
$$
X_A = \operatorname{Res}_{A/\Bbbk}(X \times_{\Bbbk} A),
$$
where $\operatorname{Res}_{A/\Bbbk}$ is the functor of Weil restriction of scalars.
